# Issue making dynamic segment available to nested route in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm having an issue making a nested route available in Ember.js

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('home', { path: '/' });
    this.resource('form', { path: '/forms/:form_id' }, function() {
        this.route('newRecord');
    });
```

I have the parent route...

```
App.FormRoute = Ember.Route.extend({....
```

Which is working.

Next I have...

```
App.FormNewRecordRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    afterModel: function() {
            this.set('newRecord', this.modelFor('form');
     }
});
```

Normally I get the URL with something like localhost/forms/9087

With the child route I'm getting localhost/undefined/newRecord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that 'localhost/undefined/newRecord' is coming from something like `{{#link-to 'newRecord'}}`.  It should probably be `{{#link-to 'form.newRecord'}}`.

Comment: No, I'm using the form.newRecord. The new route looks like this...

App.FormNewRecordRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    
      model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('form');
    }
});

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Is the `newRecord` path supposed to be for creating a new `Form` model, or is it for creating some other kind of record that is associated with a `Form`?

Comment: It's supposed to be creating a new record associated with a form.